# django-rest-swagger returns with Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, rest

I am making one API resource and I thought to use django-rest-swagger for this and I have done all the steps as provided in the django-rest-swagger [documentation](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger#quick-start)

After I tried the url http://localhost:8000/docs/ and I am unable to open and view my APIs. The error screenshot is attached below. If anyone has encountered it before please help me out.

[image: Django rest swagger error]

Comment: What happens if you try to access /api/ directly? Do you get a 500 error there?

Comment: open dev-tools in he browser and see what responses are you getting from the web-server. most likely you are getting a couple of 500 for the ajax calls swagger makes. can you post those tracebacks?

Comment: Hello @JoeyWilhelm when I try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/api-docs/` , I get this response `{"info":{"description":"","license":"","title":"","contact":"","termsOfServiceUrl":"","licenseUrl":""},"basePath":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/api-docs","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apiVersion":"","apis":[{"path":"/api"},{"path":"/api-token-auth"},{"path":"/api-token-refresh"},{"path":"/api-token-verify"}]}`

Comment: But what if you try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/`? Most likely it's an error at that endpoint which is causing Swagger to get an error.

Comment: Hello @miki725 thanks for the suggestion I have found the error was due to I was demanding some of the old fields from my database, I have changed 'mobile_number' field to 'phone_number', therefore swagger was giving me this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to old fields from the database which solved this question.

Comment: How do you remove these old fields to get this error to go away?